# Communication delay in HTML5 websocket with nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

Hi everyone and thanks for reading this.
I'm using NodeJS with WS module on server side and HTML5 WebSocket API in Firefox on client side. The operating system is windows 7 64 bit. Whenever I make a connection from the client to server, the connection forms instantaneously, but when I send some data there is a huge delay. Sometimes the messages seem to reach the server instantly, other times they reach after some seconds and even minutes and most of the time they fail to reach the server at all. I'm attaching the code from both client and server sides. If someone can help me, I'd be really thankful.

Client Side Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5225");
            ws.onopen = function (){
                alert("Sending");
                ws.send("SOME DATA !");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Server Side Code

```
var WebSocketServer = require('./ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port:5225});
var ws;

wss.on('connection',function (wsock){
    console.log("Connection Recieved");

    ws = wsock;

    ws.on('message',onnMessage);

    ws.on('close',onnClose);
});

function onnMessage(data){
        console.log("Data Recieved : "+data);
}

function onnClose(){
        console.log("Connection closed");
}
```

Comment: have you tried with 127.0.0.1, and I'd suggest testing with Google Chrome. It's Devtools(ctrl+shift+j) are integrated into the browser so are more dependable that say firefox+firebug. I'd also suggest wrapping the websock client-side code in `window.onload = function(){}`; as of right now your code is executing before the DOM is ready

Comment: I'd also suggest removing `var ` from before the websocket constructor. You issue may be the var is going out of scope(and garbage collected) before the onopen event is triggering.

Comment: Thank you everyone for answering. My initial suspect was also the garbage collector but I've made all the precautionary measures and now I don't think that's causing the problem. I haven't solved the issue yet but I don't think its caused by my client and server code. This might be because the node.js is running from command prompt in a windows environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to test at the moment, but I believe the issue is your websocket variable(`ws`) is out of scope inside the `.onopen()` event or the variable is being freed by the garbage collector before the event fires. To fix this, create the socket as a global(or to an object in the global scope):

```
<script>
    window.ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5225");
    ws.onopen = function (){
        alert("Sending");
        ws.send("SOME DATA !");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the `ws` object inside the `onopen` handler use the `this` reference, like so:

```
        ws.onopen = function (){
            alert("Sending");
            this.send("SOME DATA !");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[ws example](https://gist.github.com/3782229)

I made an example.
It handles only text and the size of the text is limited to 64k.

Basically, ws is not a simple socket. You need to follow the ws protocal to parse the data in the server side.